# Inputting a formula over a column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I have this formula `=1+ LEN(AT2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AT2, "+", ""))` that I want to apply over a column AU, that dynamically changes the variable (AT2 in this case) as iterates to the next row e.g. AT2, AT3, AT4.

Currently, this code keeps getting thrown an

> application/object error

and I can't seem to get around it. Essentially what I want the formula to do is count the number of "+" that occur in the column before and add 1 to that number. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

```
With wsIt
    Range("AU2:AU" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEN(AT2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AT2, " + ", ""))"
End With
```

Comment: Just `for` loop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just that you just need to double up on the quotes, when using them inside the formula:

```
Range("AU2:AU" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEN(AT2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AT2, "" + "", """"))"
```

Note: Be aware that this is searching for `[space]+[space]` to substitute, so it won't substitute a blank for `asd+asd`, just `asd + asd`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic formula for each cell AT2, AT3, AT4... use `FormulaR1C1`, count the criteria "+" without spaces, and double Quotation marks `""+""` `""""`:

```
.Range("AU2:AU" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1]) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1], ""+"", """"))+1"
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other responses, you need to double-up double quotes within a quoted string. Alternately you can use methods that reproduce the same results without requiring quotes.

```
With wsIt
    Range("AU2:AU" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEN(AT2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AT2, CHAR(41), TEXT(,)))"
End With
```

Comment: this ran! But for some reason, ran on the incorrect worksheet not with wsIt which was set to be Sheet1 in my case Dim wsIt As Worksheet
Set wsIt = Sheets("Sheet1"). Is there something I'm missing? @Jeeped

Comment: Additionally, I was wondering if I could add the 1+ to this formula such that even cells with no "+" get the value 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Shin to your first question, add `wslt.` before `Range` to make sure it uses the range on that worksheet. To your second point, you could do an `If(Or(...))` statement.

Comment: update, meant to bechar(43) and I just used a helper column to add 1+ to each result, thanks!

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Shin "used a helper column to add 1..." - couldn't you just add `+1` to the formula? So any 0 result becomes 1, and say 3 becomes 4?

Answer (score 0):

Missing a "." in front of `Range` - should be:

```
With wsIt
    .Range("AU2:AU" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEN(AT2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(AT2, " + ", ""))"
End With
```

The other answers regarding """" also apply - could use `chr(34)` to place a quote as well.